# How to write sub queries with LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm trying to write a similar query with LINQ

```
select DISTINCT(m.MatchID), 
    (select TeamName 
     from tbl_TournamentTeams 
     where TeamID = m.Team1), 
    (select TeamName 
     from tbl_TournamentTeams 
     where TeamID = m.Team2) 
     from tbl_TournamentTeams t, tbl_Match m 
     where t.TournamentID = m.TournamentID
```

SQL tbl_TournamentTeams table design,

```
Create Table tbl_TournamentTeams(
TeamID int primary key Identity,
TournamentID int Foreign key references tbl_Tournament(TournamentID),
TeamName varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

SQL tbl_Match table design,

```
Create Table tbl_Match(
MatchID int primary key Identity,
TournamentID int Foreign key references tbl_Tournament(TournamentID),
Team1 int Foreign key references tbl_TournamentTeams(TeamID),
Team2 int Foreign key references tbl_TournamentTeams(TeamID),
StartTime DateTime not null,
MatchBetAmount int not null
);
```

Please let me know will i be able to write a similar query with LINQ. Thanks

I want to get TeamName for every match from the linq query, currently i'm just able to fetch the teamId for a match. Please let me know how to get the TeamName details as well with the below query,

```
 var res = dbEntity.tbl_Match.Join(dbEntity.tbl_TournamentTeams,
                                            m => m.TournamentID,
                                            t => t.TournamentID,
                                            (m, t) => new
                                            {
                                                MatchID = m.MatchID,
                                                MatchTeam1 = m.Team1,
                                                MatchTeam2 = m.Team2,
                                                TournamentID =t.TournamentID

                                                // How to print the team name details as well here, where currently i'm just able to fetch the teamID
                                            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume team1 and team2 doesn't contains null values

```
 dbEntity.tbl_Match.Select(m => new{
     m.Id,
    Team1Name=dbEntity.TournamentTeams.SingleOrDefault(t => t.id=m.Team1).Name,
    Team2Name =dbEntity.TournamentTeams.SingleOrDefault(t => t.id=m.Team2).Name
     })
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The solution did work for me with minor changes as below,


                var res = dbEntity.tbl_Match.Select(m => new
                {
                    m.MatchID,
                    Team1Name = dbEntity.tbl_TournamentTeams.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TeamID == m.Team1),
                    Team2Name = dbEntity.tbl_TournamentTeams.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TeamID == m.Team2)
                });